# Logic App- How to read Batch messages from a queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

how to read a batch messages from queue then add all the json into one

here is what I have

I wan for simplicity trigger logic app to read from a queue if there are 5 messages then I need the JSON to be added into one ..for example see below (not sure if this is the right order)
The JSON I am sending to the queue is:

```
[ { "fname":"1", "lname":"1" } ]
[ { "fname":"2", "lname":"2" } ]
[ { "fname":"3", "lname":"3" } ]
[ { "fname":"4", "lname":"4" } ]
[ { "fname":"5", "lname":"5" } ]
```

[image]

then expected JSON output

```
[
  {
    "fname": "1",
    "lname": "1"
  },
  {
    "fname": "2",
    "lname": "2"
  },
  {
    "fname": "3",
    "lname": "3"
  },
  {
    "fname": "4",
    "lname": "4"
  },
  {
    "fname": "5",
    "lname": "5"
  }
]
```

***********************************************UPDAtE*******************************************************

Now I Just need the email to be sent once..it is being sent multiple times..for example:
Instead of getting one email with 
[ { "fname":"1", "lname":"1" },{ "fname":"2", "lname":"2" }

I get one email:
[ { "fname":"1", "lname":"1" } ]

then another email
[ { "fname":"1", "lname":"1" },{ "fname":"2", "lname":"2" } ]

Basically I need to get the end result of JSON so I can later one pass it to the Database

[image]

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution I provided below works ? If still have any problem or I misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why did you use "Get message from a queue" action in your logic app. According to my understanding, you create a batch sender to send the five messages, then trigger the batch receiver. And you want to convert the five json message to the format you expected. So I provide my test steps below for your reference. (in my logic app, I set the "Message Count" as "3" for ease of testing)

**1.** I created a batch receiver trigger and below is all of the actions under the batch receiver.
[image]

**2.** Then the details of the "For each" loop shown as below:
[image]

The expression in the screenshot above is:

```
union(variables('result'), items('For_each')['content'])
```

**3.** You'd better modify the setting of the "For each" loop by click the "**Settings**" and enable "**Concurrency Control**" and change the "**Degree of Parallelism**" to "1".
[image]
[image]

**4.** Then I create another logic app as the batch sender.
[image]

Run this logic app(batch sender) three times, send the json messages one by one.

**5.** Now go back to the first logic app(the batch receiver), and check the `result` variable in the third loop of the "For each" loop(in logic app "runs history"). We can see the result shown as below:
[image]

**Update:**

Change step4(the batch sender logic app) as below:

**4.1** Initialize a variable named "message" and use "Get messages from a queue (peek-lock)" action to get the messages in your queue.
[image]

**4.2** Use a "For each" to loop the "Body" from the queue and use the variable "message" to store the "Content" of the queue in each loop. Then put the variable "message" into the batch sender.(please note we can't put the "Content" into the batch sender directly because the "Content" is like a binary string, we need to use a variable to store then put it into batch sender, then it will be the json `[ { "fname":"1", "lname":"1" } ]`).
[image]
Don't forget to change the setting of this "For each" action, otherwise the result will be incorrect.
[image]

**2.1** In step2, please change the expression from

```
union(variables('result'), items('For_each')['content'])
```

to

```
union(variables('result'), json(items('For_each')['content']))
```

**Update2:**

In the batch receiver logic app, I initialize a variable named "result", it is used to store the latest json value of each loop in "For each". So just move your "Send an email(v2)" outside the "For each" and send the email with the variable "result" as the "Body". Please refer to my logic app below:

Move the "Send an email(v2)" action outside the "For each" loop and try to put the variable "result" into the "Body" of the email. But we can not find it in the "Dynamic content", so please type it by the expression.
[image]

After that, we will receive only one email from the logic app.

Comment: @HuryShey in step 4 how can my batch sender read from a service bus queue ? this is the gap I have

Comment: @rgoal Hi, please check the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: Thank Hury it is working with one minor issue...it is sending multiple emails instead f one...see update section on top for details

Comment: Hi @rgoal Please refer to the "Update2" in my answer.

Comment: it is perfect, one last question..how to ensure that the batch receiver is completed before the batch sender process the next batch of messages?

Comment: @rgoal Why do you want the the batch receiver complete before the batch sender process the next batch of message ? According to my understanding, even if the batch receiver doesn't complete, the next batch of messages will trigger another instance of batch receiver logic app. Is it right ?

Comment: I need the batch receiver to be completed in order to avoid database deadlock ...I will replace the email step with the a sql stored procedure...does it make sense?

Comment: @rgoal You can configure the batch receiver trigger's "Schedule", for example set it as 5 minutes. 5 minutes is enough for the batch receiver logic complete all of its actions.

Comment: I am sure you meant change the schedule of the batch sender right? but anyways i there  better way than relying on the schedule ? in other words, we the sl server might be slow for whatever reason then If we send another request before it finishes the first one...it might cause deadlock...Note:i am not going to read 2 messages at the time imagin I am reading 1000 messages and passing all that json to a DB

Comment: @rgoal Sorry, I'm afraid there isn't a good solution for this problem because the batch receiver trigger doesn't have "Concurrency Control" setting. I can provide another solution for your reference(but maybe not so good).

Comment: @rgoal In batch receiver logic app, when it starts to insert the 1000 messages into sql server, you can add an sql update action(update a table in another sql server) to set a value "isInserting"(0 or 1). And add a condition before start insert the 1000 messages(query the new table, if "isInserting" is 0, do the following insert operation). You can use a [Until loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop) to implement this condition operation. Until the "isInserting" is 0, otherwise continue waiting and query the "isInserting" value again.